# Distributing and Updating Software Applications to Linux envaranment

Tags: linux, repository, yum, apt-get, software-distribution

Currently I'm manually distributing and updating two applications over 50 computers running **CentOS 6.5** and **Ubuntu 14.04**. Each time the new version is available for either of my applications,i have to copy all files and update it in all the computers by **manually**.its very time consuming and frustrating.

to avoid this manual process over 50 computers,I like to maintain a **central server** that contain the latest version of the applications and whenever need to **install** or **update** just type a command in client pc like we use in CentOS and Ubuntu to install a software

in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

and in Cent OS

```
sudo yum install vlc
```

one of the programs written in java and other is written in python

I google it and can't find any good and useful source about how to do this.
some one alrady done this or knows how to achive this please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create packages to make this happen.

Ubuntu uses the Debian package format, so you can use Debian's [New Maintainer's Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/), which is the canonical tutorial on how to create a Debian package. It makes the assumption that you're going to upload the package to Debian, which in your case isn't true, but that just means you need to skip some sections of the document.

For RPM, there isn't such a document AFAIK, but there is the book 'max rpm' (which unfortunately is somewhat outdated), and fedora has augmented that with some guidelines and best practices which they've put on their wiki. Since RHEL is created by forking fedora and stabilizing that, and since CentOS is based on RHEL, what goes for fedora goes for CentOS, too.

These methods will create packages manually, which is always the best way and will result in the least problems afterwards. However, they take time. If you don't want to spend that time, there are also a few options to generate packages which will automate part or all of the job for you. Personally, however, I'm not a fan of these methods and therefore wouldn't recommend them.

Finally, another option is to not create packages, but to use a config management system like puppet to automate the deployment. It's even available in Ubuntu and EPEL.

**edit** I notice you may actually be asking about creating a repository instead. That's a different thing. There are several tools to help you do that; at core, all they do is run `createrepo` for RPM packages, or `dpkg-scanpackages` for debian packages. You can do that yourself, or investigate time in a tool like reprepro or aptly or some such.

Comment: yes my requirement is to create a repository in server